# Read database from Android phone

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to export an SQLite database from an Android phone to a computer.

I know you can do it with the pull command and shell, but it seems
   that this is only possible on rooted phones (or that's what I read).
   Is this true or is there another way to pull the db files?

At the moment I copy the whole database file to the external storage to be able to access it from a PC I don't know if this is good or bad practice.

What are my options here?

Comment: I don't think you need to have a rooted phone to use `adb pull`.

Comment: @AleksG I faced the same problem and tried adb pull, but you cannot pull files from /data/data without rooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to listen for a broadcast and copy the database to a place where I can pull the file. For me this was the external storage.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can't get it with adb pull, you could try to e-mail it to yourself or use dropbox or something?

Read: [How to attach database file to an Email in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906703/how-to-attach-database-file-to-an-email-in-android)

Comment: That's not really a good option, I want to be able to get it through USB.